# How to fetch the "total downloads" and "daily downloads" of an Apple Appstore App via Apps connect API?

Tags: ios, api, download, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to fetch the "Total installations" and "Daily downloads" of my apple app via apps connect api. Here I'm trying to use "Sales and Trends Report". But, I couldn't find the exact report name and required filters.

API currently using:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/download_sales_and_trends_reports

Report Required as in App store connect:
[image]